# How can I rename the elements of the list within another list using for loop?

Tags: r, list

Below is just a little example from a larger dataset

```
x <- data.frame(a = c(1,2), b= c(3,4))
y <- data.frame(a = c(1,2), b= c(3,4), c=c(5,6))
fir <- list(x=x,y=y)

w <- data.frame(a = c(7,8), b= c(9,10))
z <- data.frame(a = c(11,12), b= c(13,14), c=c(15,16), d=c(17,18))

sec <- list(x=w,y=z)

list <- list(fir,sec)

$pri
$pri$x
  a b
1 1 3
2 2 4

$pri$y
  a b c
1 1 3 5
2 2 4 6


$sec
$sec$x
  a  b
1 7  9
2 8 10

$sec$y
   a  b  c  d
1 11 13 15 17
2 12 14 16 18
```

How do i rename the list sec elements names to respective `x1` or `xsec` and `y1` or `ysec`?

Like this

```
$pri
$pri$x
  a b
1 1 3
2 2 4

$pri$y
  a b c
1 1 3 5
2 2 4 6


$sec
$sec$x1
  a  b
1 7  9
2 8 10

$sec$y1
   a  b  c  d
1 11 13 15 17
2 12 14 16 18
```

or

```
$pri
$pri$x
  a b
1 1 3
2 2 4

$pri$y
  a b c
1 1 3 5
2 2 4 6


$sec
$sec$xsec
  a  b
1 7  9
2 8 10

$sec$ysec
   a  b  c  d
1 11 13 15 17
2 12 14 16 18
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with lists, it's often useful to `map` functions over them rather than using loops. For this case, you can use an *indexed map* to modify the names of each sub-list element according to the index of its parent list:

```
library(purrr)

renamed_list <- imap(list, function(l, n) {names(l) <- paste0(names(l), n) ; l})

str(renamed_list)

#> List of 2
#>  $ :List of 2
#>   ..$ x1:'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   .. ..$ a: num [1:2] 1 2
#>   .. ..$ b: num [1:2] 3 4
#>   ..$ y1:'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
#>   .. ..$ a: num [1:2] 1 2
#>   .. ..$ b: num [1:2] 3 4
#>   .. ..$ c: num [1:2] 5 6
#>  $ :List of 2
#>   ..$ x2:'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   .. ..$ a: num [1:2] 7 8
#>   .. ..$ b: num [1:2] 9 10
#>   ..$ y2:'data.frame':   2 obs. of  4 variables:
#>   .. ..$ a: num [1:2] 11 12
#>   .. ..$ b: num [1:2] 13 14
#>   .. ..$ c: num [1:2] 15 16
#>   .. ..$ d: num [1:2] 17 18
```

There's a bit to unpack in the `imap` line, so I'll go through it. `imap` takes a list (in this case your `list <- list(fir, sec)`) and the names or indices of its elements, and applies some function to each element that utilizes the names/indices.

I condensed it down to one line above, but the function I'm applying to each list is:

```
function(l, n) {
  names(l) <- paste0(names(l), n)
  return(l)
}
```

`l` is a sub-list, and `n` is the name (if named) or index (if not named) of the parent list. We take the names of our sub-list and append the name/index to whatever was already there. In this case, the parent lists don't have named elements, so we append the index and get sub-lists with elements named `x1, y1`, `x2, y2`, and so on.